# Using a variable outside of a function

Tags: php, function

I have the following (summarised) code

```
define pauls_code($a, $b)
{
$c = $a + $b;
echo $a;
echo $b;
}
pauls_code(1,2);
echo $c;  //  how do I get this to print outside of the function?   I have tried everything. I am hoping to see 123
```

Comment: why don't you return the value from the function and call the function from outside , how do you expect to access a variable out of its scope ?

Comment: Use `global`. Or make it a return. Or pass a variable by reference.

Comment: There are so many syntax errors. You should use return in the function

Comment: don't make a function for the sake of it, give it a clear purpose and a meaningful name...

Answer (score 3):

make your function like this and return the `$c`

```
function pauls_code($a, $b){
$c = $a + $b;
return $c;
}
echo pauls_code(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To declare a function in php you simply put `function pauls_code($param1, $param2)` not `define`

You can not access `$c` outside of the function, read more about scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php